# "error": "wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

When I debug my code, the error appears in this line: 
`val_emails = get_validate(emails , true)`

The error message:

> ```
> "error": "wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)"
> ```

The following code runs in the background for method
- `get_emails_list`

```rb
def send_one(monitor, approve_monitor)
   emails = Mail.get_emails_list(Mail::MailOne)
    puts "=========================================="
    puts "hello"

    val_emails = get_validate(emails , true)
    puts "=========================================="
    puts "world"
    if val_emails != ''
        puts "hello"
    end
end
```

Code for method `get_emails_list`:

```
def self.get_emails_list(event_name)
        Mail.get_all_emails_list(event_name)
end

class << self
    def get_all_emails_list(event_name)
            event_emails = Mail.where(:event_name => event_name).select('email')
            emails = ''
            event_emails.each {  |e|
                emails = emails + e.email + ' , '
            }
            return emails
     end
        handle_asynchronously :get_all_emails_list,
                                                    run_at: proc { 0.seconds.from_now },
                                                    :priority => 0, :queue => 'email_list'
end
```

I am using `rails 5.2` & gem `delayed_job_active_record`

**updated** The code works when I delete following line:

```
handle_asynchronously :get_all_emails_list,
    run_at: proc { 0.seconds.from_now },
    :priority => 0, :queue => 'email_list'
```

Comment: Shouldnt this puts hello be puts "hello" ?

Comment: @Grumpy this wrong for my writing but  error  in this line `val_emails = get_validate(emails , true)`

Comment: @Grumpy already code stop in `val_emails = get_validate(emails , true)`

Comment: Show the get_validate function

Comment: The error says 1 given, expected 0, that one has 2. Isnt this the one failing emails = Mail.get_emails_list(Mail::MailOne), thats has one argument.

Comment: yes when debug code not enter `get_all_emails_list`